# Slurm, run job only when sufficient memory is available

Tags: slurm

How can i run a job on slurm using srun such that it goes into queue when the neccessary resources such as memory per gpu is not available, and only runs when it is.

I tried using the flag `mem-per-gpu`, but it doesnt obey the memory requirement at all and i keep running into OOM issues. Since the server is actively being used, i cant keep track of when the gpus are freed up.

The flag --exclusive also reserves the entire node which may not be helpful as i only want to use a  certain number of gpus within the node.

Expect to queue the job until sufficient memory is available.

Comment: In theory, SLURM should only give you the resources once they are available. Chances are that not all jobs that are sharing the node asked for enough memory. SLURM should catch them on time before the OoM kicks in, but there are certain configurations that cannot guarantee that in a timely manner. Talk with your SysAdmins and check if cgroups is enabled for the resource control and limitation.